# how to continue 'Listening for transport dt_socket at address'

Tags: java, remote-debugging

I set up java remote debugger with suspend=y. sometimes i don't want to attach debugger and just want to see my cmdline tool continue. is there a way to continue without having to attach debugger but still keep suspend=y?

Answer (score 0):

No. However, you can attach debugger, hit resume and then detach debugger.